# Display a video in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've written this to see a video in an android fragment.

```
public class Video_fragment extends Fragment{

private View rootView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Activity my_activity = this.getActivity();
    VideoView vid1 = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri path = Uri.parse("https://pdlvimeocdn-a.akamaihd.net/70364/541/376889773.mp4?token2=1435321048_5e268d54554862ae1b8096d54bab15e8&amp;aksessionid=69a5f78c453bf170");
    vid1.setVideoURI(path);
    vid1.setMediaController(new MediaController(my_activity));
    vid1.start();


}
```

}

But I get that error:

```
06-29 14:20:55.724    8979-8979/com.example.aviad.uefa E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
06-29 14:20:55.724    8979-8979/com.example.aviad.uefa E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
06-29 14:20:55.734    8979-8979/com.example.aviad.uefa E/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ Unable to create media player
```

Tried to find something that could help but I didn't find anything.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you added internet permission in manifest?

Comment: I dont think so.. 
how can i do that ?
or if i got the video on my computer where/how i make that work ?